# Can I pull the values of the filters in my PBIX report into a text file for testing?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I have a Power BI Pbix file. I do not want to everyday manually test the basic checks that we have decided, such as filters must be cleared. Can I get the values for these filters in some way to a file?

If so I can compare the files each time to make sure the filters are empty as per my main text file.

Is this possible?

Are there any other ways where I can test a PBIX file programmatically?

Comment: Are you sharing the PBI file on the network or using it in the service?

Comment: Hi @Jon. The plan is to publish to a workspace in service later but I want to try this out locally first.

Comment: You can't interact with the desktop file programmatically, it has been requested on the power bi ideas site. I would test in the service, and for example disable persistent filters